# Error when creating SparkSession in PySpark Jupitor Note Book

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am practicing with Jupiter Notebook and pyspark. When I run `spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('Srikanth').getOrCreate()`, then I am getting the error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_592\618625653.py in <module>
----> 1 spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('Srikanth').getOrCreate()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    267                         sparkConf.set(key, value)
    268                     # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
--> 269                     sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    270                     # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
    271                     # by all sessions.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    481         with SparkContext._lock:
    482             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 483                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    484             assert SparkContext._active_spark_context is not None
    485             return SparkContext._active_spark_context

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls, udf_profiler_cls)
    193             )
    194 
--> 195         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    196         try:
    197             self._do_init(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    415         with SparkContext._lock:
    416             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 417                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    418                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    419 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(conf, popen_kwargs)
    104 
    105             if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 106                 raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
    107 
    108             with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:

RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Session is not creating

Comment: Are you sure you have java installed and set JAVA_HOME on your path ?

Comment: After I setup JAVA_HOME it is working fine.